# Symfony 2.8 - Access (local) JSON from view?

Tags: php, json, symfony, twig, assetic

I have a symfony2 app with a couple of bundles and assetic which handles my css and js.

I would like to also deploy a dataset which the view will need to draw a map - let's call it `map.json`.

Where should I put this file so I can access it with relative ease from a view (twig template) or other javascript file?

---

EDIT: In one of the controllers (written a couple years ago...) I retrieved a JSON document as follows:

```
$myFile = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/common/path/to/file.json';
$parameters['myFile'] = file_get_contents($myFile);
```

And then returned `$parameters` with the view. It works, but seems a bit strange... and it doesn't help me if I need to access the file from an external javascript file (eg. `myJs.js`).

I also don't particularly like having to hardcode asset paths, especially if I also have to do it to access it via external javascript.

Comment: why don't you create an endpoint like an API just for displaying this JSON file ? If you don't want to hardcode the assets you can use an envvar but it looks normal in that case to use the path to your file, how would you like to access it ?

Answer (score 0):

The location of your `json-file` must be owned by `www-data` user and not be blocked by `.htaccess` so you either put it into the `web` folder, or put it in one of your `bundles` `Resources/public` folders **which are simlinked** to your webfolder.